# Mapping list of checked InputCheckbox elements to list of string on the form model

Tags: data-binding, blazor

I have a list of strings that I'd like to list in a form. Users should be able to check the boxes for the strings they want and I'd like to bind the list values back to the form model.

Let's take a look at the code I've figured out so far:

```
//mypage.razor
//...
<EditForm Model="MyModel">
  @foreach(var opt in AvailableOptions) 
  {
    <label for="option-@opt">@opt</label>
    <InputCheckbox id="option-@opt" name="option-@opt" type="checkbox" @bind="@(/* bind to what?!? */)"/>
  }
</EditForm>

@code 
{
  private MyPageModel MyModel = new ();
  private List<string> AvailableOptions = new List<string> 
  {
    "Apple",
    "Banana",
    "Cherry"
  }

  public class MyPageModel 
  {
    public List<string> SelectedValues { get; set; } = new();
  }
}
```

So this is where I started at. Of course, while I can show the value of the label as part of the loop, it's not clear how I'd bind the boolean value of the Checked property to the form model, especially not when I'm wanting to save the `opt` string value to the form model's list (for checked values) and not a collection of boolean values.

Looking at an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598221/blazor-inputcheckbox) to a similar question, the thought is that I'd create a "carrier" class with the name and a boolean like:

```
public class MyCheckedOption
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public bool IsChecked {get; set;}
}
```

Now, when I bind in the InputCheckbox, I can now set AvailableOptions to a list of `MyPageModel` and do `@bind="opt.IsChecked"`, but this now binds to `MyPageModel` and doesn't bind back to my form model.

Now, in my OnValidSubmit, I could harvest the values of these and populate my form model, but that doesn't seem ideal.

Rather, is there some way to map the boolean of the checked properties (as populated by something in my code behind) to a list of string (wherein the value I want to use is another property of the "carrier" class I'm looping through a list of) that I can store directly on the form model?

Comment: The only thing a Form Model really does is provide a template and some functionality for validation.  But for objects that only consist of a display name and a boolean value, there's nothing to validate.  Unless you are adding more inputs, I wouldn't even bother with EditForm at all.  I'd only have a `List<MyCheckedOption>` for both the display and the Checkbox binding.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Linq's Select method to convert your list to something else-- in the following case, a list of `MyCheckableOption` objects.  Later, when you want to do something with the list, you can do the same in reverse to get back to a `List<string>`

```
@foreach (var opt in AvailableOptions)
{
    <label>@opt.Name&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="checkbox" @bind="opt.IsChecked" />
    <br/>
}
<hr />
@foreach (var item in AvailableOptions.Where(option => option.IsChecked))
{
    <div>@item.Name has been selected. </div>
}
@code
{
    private List<MyCheckableOption> AvailableOptions = new List<string>
    {
        "Apple",
        "Banana",
        "Cherry"
    }
    .Select(option => new MyCheckableOption {Name = option }).ToList();

    public class MyCheckableOption
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```